# JavaScript: Specifying the Order of Properties In An Object

Tags: javascript, html, json

OK. I've been looking at the supplied answers, and they all seem to be very specific. I need to know this in a general sense.

**ISSUE**

I have a couple of JS objects. I use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to compare them (see if an object is "dirty").

However, stringify renders the object exactly as it is set in memory, so it takes whatever order the properties of that object happen to be in.

If I delete a property, then restore it, that could change the order.

I'll show a simple HTML example in a second. What I want, is for the **RESTORE** section to look exactly like the **BEFORE** section.

I'm wondering if there is a basic, browser-generic way to do that.

**EXAMPLE**

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test JS</title></head>
    <body>
        <dl>
            <dt><strong><big>BEFORE:</big></strong></dt>
                <dd><em><strong>Object A:</strong> <span id="objA1"></span></em></dd>
                <dd><em><strong>Object B:</strong> <span id="objB1"></span></em></dd>
            <dt><strong><big>AFTER:</big></strong></dt>
                <dd><em><strong>Object A:</strong> <span id="objA2"></span></em></dd>
                <dd><em><strong>Object B:</strong> <span id="objB2"></span></em></dd>
            <dt><strong><big>RESTORE:</big></strong></dt>
                <dd><em><strong>Object A:</strong> <span id="objA3"></span></em></dd>
                <dd><em><strong>Object B:</strong> <span id="objB3"></span></em></dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var objA, objB;

            function setUpObjects ( ) {
                objA = new Object;
                objB = new Object;

                objA.someProperty = 'HIHOWAYA';
                objB.someProperty = 'HIHOWAYA';
                objA.someOtherProperty = 'JUSTFINETHX';
                objB.someOtherProperty = 'JUSTFINETHX';
            };

            function deleteAProperty ( ) {
                delete objA.someProperty;
            };

            function restoreAProperty ( ) {
                objA.someProperty = 'HIHOWAYA';
            };

            function displayObjects ( inIndex ) {
                document.getElementById ( 'objA' + inIndex.toString() ).innerHTML = JSON.stringify ( objA );
                document.getElementById ( 'objB' + inIndex.toString() ).innerHTML = JSON.stringify ( objB );
            };

            setUpObjects();
            displayObjects ( 1 );
            deleteAProperty();
            displayObjects ( 2 );
            restoreAProperty();
            displayObjects ( 3 );

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a basic, browser-generic way to do that.

No. You'll have to create your own JSON serializer if you want to ensure that the properties in the JSON text are output in a defined order, as neither JSON nor JavaScript apply order to the properties. This is only useful in that you can then compare *texts* in a meaningful way; once you *parse* that text, order is once again not guaranteed.

Comment: That's pretty much what I figgered. I'll greencheck you when the time limit is up. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. I did figure out how to keep the issue from happening in my specific implementation, but was wondering if there is a more general way of doing things.

Comment: @MAGSHARE: For what it's worth, a custom serializer isn't that hard if you don't have to support pretty-printing and a replacer function. You can lean on `JSON.stringify` for the individual bits of it. Curiously enough I had to do this just the other day (code is copyrighted, though, so I can't hand it out), and it ended up being about 20 lines. Basically I branched on the type of the value being output and added special handling for arrays (so I could call my version on their entries) and objects (so I could output the keys in a particular order). *(cont'd)*

Comment: @MAGSHARE: *(continuing)* The only tricky bit was that `undefined` and function references are handled specially in arrays: The result in `null` in the array, whereas if you have an object property whose value is `undefined` or a function reference, the property is left out entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript objects  - like most basic hash table data structures - offer no guarantee as to the order of their keys: you should not rely on whatever order you observe empirically. If you want to iterate over the properties in a robust, predictable order, you'll have to complement your objects with some other data structure, e.g an array of the keys.